# How to get the amplitude when blowing into MIC on android device

Tags: android

How to get the amplitude when blowing into MIC in android device.

```
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
   recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);

   Timer timer = new Timer();
   timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RecorderTask(recorder), 0, 1000);

private class RecorderTask extends TimerTask {
private MediaRecorder recorder;

public RecorderTask(MediaRecorder recorder) {
    this.recorder = recorder;
}

public void run() {
    Log.v("", "amplitude is" + recorder.getMaxAmplitude());
}
}
```

I am getting an error:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20927): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed.
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20927): at android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 10):

```
public boolean isBlowing()
    {
        boolean recorder=true;

        int minSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        AudioRecord ar = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 8000,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,minSize);


        short[] buffer = new short[minSize];

        ar.startRecording();
        while(recorder)
        {

            ar.read(buffer, 0, minSize);
            for (short s : buffer) 
            {
                if (Math.abs(s) > 27000)   //DETECT VOLUME (IF I BLOW IN THE MIC)
                {
                    blow_value=Math.abs(s);
                    System.out.println("Blow Value="+blow_value);
                    ar.stop();
                    recorder=false;

                    return true;

                }

            }
        }
        return false;

    }
```

Comment: Its detecting all the sounds have value greater than 27000. How can we detect that its sound of blow.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up permissions on your manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the recorder, as well as set several methods. Look at the documentation for [MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) to see how to do this. I've used this method and it works quite well.