# ANDROID - Measuring the level of sound a user made and displaying it

Tags: java, android, eclipse, audio, android-mediarecorder

I am currently writing an app that shows how loud the user is. I currently have it recording the sound when they press record using `MediaRecorder` and then allowing them to listen to that recording again by pressing play, this uses `MediaPlayer`.

I now want to some how output how loud the noise was that they recorded. Due to using the `MediaRecorder` I am trying to retrieve the loudness through`.getMaxAplitude()`. Using this I am then trying to display it in a textview so the user can see their results.

Therefore in doing this I have the current code in the begin recording function is

```
 recorder = new MediaRecorder();
 recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
 recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
 recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
 recorder.setOutputFile(OUTPUT_FILE);
 recorder.prepare();
 recorder.start();

 int test = recorder.getMaxAmplitude();
 txtView.setText(test);
```

As you would have already guessed this doesn't work, the recording the audio does work but acquiring or showing the amplitude to the user isn't

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try using AudioManager?

Comment: from my knowledge doesn't that just control things like ringtone volume etc? What I m doing is having the user shout into the mic and then measure the level of noise they created when shouting or will it help with that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android MediaRecorder getMaxAmplitude always returns 0 on LG Optimus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600364/android-mediarecorder-getmaxamplitude-always-returns-0-on-lg-optimus)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you can take a view on the stackoverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977728/how-to-get-the-amplitude-when-blowing-into-mic-on-android-device).

Also a similar kind of project is available in [code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/android-labs/source/browse/trunk/NoiseAlert/src/com/google/android/noisealert/)

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot. Another thing was that i needed to update the UI in order to get it to work properly