# How to detect beginning of speech and end of speech in Android like Talking Tom cat?

Tags: android, audio, audiorecord

I am able to record audio, change the sampling rate and play it back. But, how can I detect beginning and end of audio without touching the screen?

Not looking for code, just a push to the right direction.

Comment: Why don't you look at intensity(i.e volume based) of voice. ?

Comment: Have you checked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181449/android-detect-sound-level) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26645060/4596556)?. Check the amplitude of the sound for an interval.

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar Thanks, exactly what I needed.

Comment: @androidlab Glad it worked for you :)